# Configuring a Java syslog client to trust self-signed certificates

Tags: java, ssl, syslog, cloudbees

I am evaluating using the [CloudBees Java syslog client](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/syslog-java-client) to read a log file and send its contents off to a syslog receiver I've already built.

My *understanding* is that its `TcpSyslogMessageSender` can be used to send messages over TLS using SSL certificates. However I don't see any "trust" configurations anywhere, which makes me wonder if self-signed (non-CA-signed) certificates are supported by this library at all?

If my syslog receiver on the other end presents this client with a self-signed certificate, how can I configure the `TcpSyslogMessageSender` to trust it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create SSLcontext and set it in TcpSyslogMessageSender

For building ssl context I used org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore because building ssl context with java tools is more difficult

Example

```java
public class SyslogTestCloudBees {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
            //Initialization 
            TcpSyslogMessageSender messageSender = new TcpSyslogMessageSender();
            messageSender.setDefaultMessageHostname("myhostname"); 
            messageSender.setDefaultAppName("myapp");
            messageSender.setDefaultFacility(Facility.USER);
            messageSender.setDefaultSeverity(Severity.INFORMATIONAL);
            messageSender.setSyslogServerHostname("127.0.0.1");
            messageSender.setSyslogServerPort(1234);
           
            //SSL part
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(new File("path/to/truststore"), 
                                                "truststorepassword".toCharArray())
                    .build();

            messageSender.setSSLContext(sslContext);
            messageSender.setSsl(true);

             // send a Syslog message
            messageSender.sendMessage("This is a test message");
        }
}
```

Comment: Also you can try to setup truststore with vm parameters -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password OR you can add your certificates to default truststore - /jre_home/lib/security/cacerts (default password changeme), but it setup certs for whole application, and also I think that way with code is the best one, because it's explicit

Comment: Nit: the default cacerts password is changeit (not me)